# alpha does not work on text (flash, as3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text, scrollbar, alpha

i'd like to make an effect with "alpha", but when i'm using a particular class to set the scrollbar on my text, the text does not respond to my alpha.
You'll see that the text does not respond to the alpha 0 at the beginning of the tween.

I'm using a good scrollbar class that i found on internet, but i can't explain why this is happening.

Here's my code in the fla that imports another class, which imports the scrollbar class ;-) :

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

var loader:Loader = new Loader;
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Rhizo.swf");
loader.load(url);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ec);

function ec (e:Event){
    var a = e.target.content;

    a.alpha = 0;
    addChild(e.target.content);
    TweenLite.to(a, 3, { x:30, alpha:1});

}
```

the document class, linked with the fla that contains the code above, where i call the scroll bar class :

```
public class ScrollBarAS3 extends MovieClip {
        public var my_scrollbar:MakeScrollBar;

        public function ScrollBarAS3() {
            my_scrollbar = new MakeScrollBar( scroll_mc, scroll_text );
            scroll_txt.selectable = true; 
        }

        public function scroll_text( n:Number ) {
            scroll_txt.scrollV = Math.round( ( scroll_txt.maxScrollV - 1 ) * n ) + 1;
        }
```

and here's the scrollbar class :

```
package {
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class MakeScrollBar extends MovieClip {
        private var host_mc:MovieClip;
        private var call_back:Function;

        private var drag_mc:MovieClip;
        private var track_mc:MovieClip;

        private var scroll_rect:Rectangle;
        private var upper_limit:Number;
        private var range:Number;

        public function MakeScrollBar( _mc:MovieClip, cb:Function ) {
            host_mc = _mc;
            call_back = cb;

            drag_mc = host_mc.drag_mc; // 
            drag_mc.buttonMode = true;
            drag_mc.mouseChildren = false
            drag_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, press_drag );
            track_mc = host_mc.track_mc;
            track_mc.buttonMode = true;
            track_mc.mouseChildren = false
            track_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, click_track );

            set_limits();
        }

        private function press_drag( event:MouseEvent ):void {
            /***************************************************/
            drag_mc.stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, release_drag, false, 0, true );
            /***************************************************/ 
            drag_mc.startDrag( false, scroll_rect );
            drag_mc.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, drag );
        }

        private function release_drag( event:MouseEvent ):void {
            drag_mc.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, drag );
            drag_mc.stage.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, release_drag );
            drag_mc.stopDrag();
        }

        private function click_track( event:MouseEvent ):void {
        }

        private function set_limits():void {
            scroll_rect = new Rectangle( track_mc.x, track_mc.y, 0, track_mc.height - drag_mc.height );
            upper_limit = track_mc.y;
            range = track_mc.height - drag_mc.height;
        }

        private function drag( event:Event ):void {
            var p = ( drag_mc.y - track_mc.y ) / range;
            call_back( p );
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know what i could do to make the alpha work?

Thanks a lot

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an AS3 point of view , you will not be able to apply transparency to a TextField unless its embedFonts property is set to true. I would suggest that the problem is with the loaded SWF but you don't provide any code for it...

//----------------------- Edit ---------------------//

What happens if you simply do this? Does the text appear?

```
function ec (e:Event){
    var a = e.target.content;

    a.alpha = 0;
    addChild(e.target.content);

}
```

Did you test the .swf locally? 
Have you tried to simply load the movie, without the ScrollBar and managed to get the alpha working?
At the moment, I don't see anything in the ScrollBar class that could interfere with the text transparency...

Comment: hi PatrickS, i put all the code that i use, the first chunk of code is  what i load, and the 2 last chunks of code are the class itself.. i tested a single movieclip with text inside it, and the alpha works, but the class does not let me do the same thing with the scrollbar.

Comment: thanks for your help, i appreciate, it seems that if i use  the scrollbar, the alpha on the text doesn't work. I don't know, there must be something i'm missing...